# fscanf parse data (format specifier) C++

Tags: c

I have a struct like so:

```
struct Office {
char city[50];
int employees;
char desc[200];
}

struct Office office[100];
```

Then I want to fill the office array within a loop until reach end of file.

here is my data:

```
Toronto
    151: This is HQ

Vancouver
    23: This is branch office

London
    12: This is euro branch
```

Take this as an example:

```
Toronto
    151: This is HQ
```

So here I want to parse it to struct:

```
city = "Toronto"
employees = 151
desc = "This is HQ"
```

Notice: After city name in the new line before the number of employess, there is TAB (4 spaces)

I have had an implementation like so, but seems it does not work properly:

```
int function LoadOffices(const char *f) {
  int res = 1;
  char buf[500];
  char city[50];
  int emp;
  char desc[200];
  struct Office offices[100];
  FILE *fp = fopen(f, "r");

  if (fp) {
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(line), fp) != nullptr) {
      if (i == 0) {
        rewind(fp);
      }
      i++;
      if (fscanf(fp, "%[^\n]", city) == 1) {
        strncpy(offices[i].city, city, 50);
      } else if (fscanf(fp, "%d[^:]:%[^\n]", &emp, desc) == 2) {
        offices[i].employees = emp;
        strncpy(offices[i].desc, desc, 200);
      }
    }
    res = 0;
  } else {
    res = 1;
  }

  fclose(fp);
  return res;
}
```

**I just want to know how to deal with TAB and empty lines**

Comment: Either you're using a *very* new compiler which uses the future C23 standard, or you're really programming in C++. The hint is the `nullptr` keyword you use.

Comment: By the way, what is the type`function` you use as return-type for `LoadOffices`?

Comment: As for your problem, I suggest you use `fgets` to read both lines. Then strip leading and trailing spaces from the lines. Then parse directly into the structure members (for the city use `fgets` to read directly into the `city` member, and if the string is empty after stripping then `continue` the loop).

Comment: The function is declared to return `function`, but `return res;` returns an `int`. Do you have `typdef int function;` somewhere? If so, why? Are you trying to make C look like PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: Where is the variable `i` defined and initialized, by the way?

Comment: Write a function to read _a single_ “office”. Then write a function that uses the first to load multiple.

Comment: _"it does not work properly"_ is not much of a problem description.

Comment: `strncpy(offices[i].city, city, 50);` is not a safe way, in general, to copy a string.  The problem is that `strncpy` does not guarantee null-termination of the destination.  Also, if you're trying to be safe, you should use e.g. `fscanf(fp, "%49[^\n]", city)`.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of your program makes a huge difference in how easy it is to approach a problem.

For loading an array of any kind of `struct` there is an idiom that you should use:

- Make a function that reads a *single* `struct`
- Have a way to determine the success or failure of that function on the stream
- Make another function that uses the first to read an array/list/whatever of that `struct`

Here is what I suggest you work on:

```
bool LoadAnOffice( FILE * fp, struct Office * office );
// Attempt to read a single office from the open stream 'fp'
// Returns success or failure

bool LoadOffices( FILE * fp, struct Office offices[], size_t * num_offices, size_t max_num_offices );
// Fill an array of offices by loading them from the open stream 'fp'
// Returns the number of offices loaded in '*num_offices'
// Reads at most 'max_num_offices'
// Returns 'true' if EOF encountered, 'false' otherwise
```

You can even add a function to do it by opening a file as you wish:

```
bool LoadOfficesFromFile( const char * filename, struct Office offices[], size_t * num_offices, size_t max_num_offices )
{
  FILE * f = fopen( filename, "r" );
  if (!f) return false;
  bool result = LoadOffices( f, offices, num_offices, max_num_offices );
  fclose( f );
  return result;
}
```

Thereafter your program can easily handle loading your offices from file:

```
int main(void)
{
  #define MAX_OFFICES 100
  struct Office offices[MAX_OFFICES];
  size_t n_offices = 0;

  if (!LoadOfficesFromFile( "offices.txt", offices, &n_offices, MAX_OFFICES ))
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "%s\n", "complain!" );
    ...
  }
```

It isn’t *short*, but it is a good way to modularize handling file I/O for structured types. You’ll find yourself using some variation of this idiom over and over and over.

Comment: Hey Dúthomhas, thanks for your suggestions, for sure I am going to apply modularity, I have written a short snippet to demonstrate my issue with fscanf and even I have tried sscanf, so I wan to know how to take the "CITY" which is does not contain ":" and "TAB" at the beginning and how to parse employees and desc which is separated by ":" and start by TAB